# Firebase Audiences - Push Notification

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm a bit confused about how Firebase Audiences are working.

I was assuming that I can send a push notification to a group of user when I created a new audiences. But as far as I understood, I need to wait for some time for new events to be logged for the audience.

My question is that, is it possible to send a push notification to a user audience instantly when I create it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible. But as mentioned in the [docs](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317509?hl=en&ref_topic=6317489#create-an-audience) (emphasis mine):

> Once created, an audience accumulates users who meet the specified criteria from that point onward by virtue of the events that their devices log. **When defining new audiences, it may take some time for the lists to populate. Before targeting an audience in Notifications or Remote Config, be sure to check the number of users for your audience to see if it looks reasonably well developed.**

It takes time to populate, so it would be best to give time for it before sending a message. You *could* still do it immediately, but it's possible that you'd be sending a message that doesn't have any recipients.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but this is really stupid. I know many other tools that you can create audiences and send push not. immediately.